# lampp php5.6 install redis via pecl

Tags: redis, ubuntu-20.04, php-5.6

I need to install redis on my lampp(php5.6.40) via pecl in mint 20

```
cd /opt/lampp/bin
sudo ./pecl install redis
```

but I got an error :

```
WARNING: channel "pecl.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "pecl channel-update pecl.php.net" to update
pecl/redis requires PHP (version >= 7.0.0), installed version is 5.6.40
```

can you help my to solve this issu, I need install redis on php5.6 because my project required php5.6 .

Comment: can you advice me, you how to setup redis on php5.6 manually

Answer (score 0):

phpredis 5.x.x are drop PHP5 support
https://pecl.php.net/package-changelog.php?package=redis

try old version install.

```
pecl install redis-4.3.0
```